# Emit elements from a list every n milliseconds

Tags: rx-java2

I have a list of elements from which i want to emit 5 of those elements separately, every number of seconds/milliseconds.

I feel like this should be working:

```
   Flowable.just(listOf<String>("1","2","3","4","5","6"))
                .flatMapIterable { it }
                .take(5)
                .delay(300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .toLiveData()
```

But I only get the latest element (5 in this case).

Whats wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to achieve this would be to split the list of strings into multiple lists with a maximum size of 5 elements, concatMap each list to a flowable with a delay of 300 milliseconds, and then use concatMapIterable to emit each string from the list individually. We want to use concatMap here instead of flatMap to preserve the order of the items and ensure they don't all emit concurrently.

Kotlin has a [chunked](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/chunked.html) operator that is helpful here.

```
Flowable.fromIterable((1..12).map { it.toString() }.chunked(5))
        .concatMap { Flowable.just(it).delay(300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) }
        .concatMapIterable { it }
        .subscribe { println(it) }
```

This will produce the following output:

```
// 300ms
1
2
3
4
5
// 600ms
6
7
8
9
10
// 900ms
11
12
```

Comment: I think i did not explain myself properly but i was able to infer the proper behavior from your answer, thanks! What i wanted was 1 .... 2 .... 3 .... 4 ... 5 separated by 300 millisecs.